# Updating search scopes without waiting

Tags: search, search-scope

When setting up a search scope, the UI says:

> Ready after next update (starts in *XY* minutes)

Is there any way to make SharePoint 2007 process the search scope at my command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Search Administration, within System Status, you can specify that the Scopes Update Schedule be set to "**On Demand**" rather than the default setting of "Automatically Scheduled Update".

Once a scope change is made, you can then kick off the update by selecting "**Update Now**" next to "Scopes Needing Update".

Alternatively, on an ad hoc basis, you could install Gary Lapointe's STSADM [extensions](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2009/02/downloads.html), one of which is **gl-updatesearchscope** as in the example:

stsadm –o gl-updatesearchscope -url "http://intranet" -name "Search Scope 1" -groups "search dropdown, advanced search".

More details [here](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/11/search-scopes-and-rules.html).